# Can I store a jQuery setter expression as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JS / jQuery and writing a countdown timer app.  There are several places in my code where I need to change the DOM using the same jQuery setter expression:

`$("#minutes").text(('0' + getTimeRemaining().minutes).slice(-2));`

This works fine, but if I feel I should store this in a variable because D.R.Y.

So I added the following to my code:

`var displayMinutes = $("#minutes").text(('0' + getTimeRemaining().minutes).slice(-2));`

What happens is a) the setter is run at the point I declare the variable and b) declaring `displayMinutes` does nothing (although it logs an object) and (c) `displayMinutes()` does nothing either (and logs that it is not a function).

My question is primarily - is it possible to store such an expression as a variable - and secondly, what I am missing about the jQuery object in general here?

My only clue from googling is that this is perhaps to do with 'this' and the bind method?

Would appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Comment: `displayMinutes ` is `$("#minutes")` ...that's how jQuery chaining works. Any setter will return `jQuery` object as per the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap it in a function like this:

```
function setMinutes(){
    $("#minutes").text(('0' + getTimeRemaining().minutes).slice(-2));  
}
```

and simply call `setMinutes` every time. But that will not improve performance. Best way could be this:

```
var setMinutes = (function(){
    var minutes = $("#minutes");
    return function(){ minutes.text(('0' + getTimeRemaining().minutes).slice(-2)); }
})()
```

Now you can still call `setMinutes`, but instead of jQuery rebuilding your minutes element every time we have stored it inside a `closure`, which means our code speeds up a little bit again. In case this looks complex, what it does is define and then call that `function` immediately. This function will *in turn* return another `function` that already knows about a variable called `minutes`, which means it does not have to computed anymore, shaving precious seconds off your execution time.

The variable you stored, by the way, is not the *function* but the *result* of said function. That's why it won't work the way you do it now.